# PHP 7 Module error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php-7

Suddenly I got conflict php 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. php run in terminal but not in browser. When I try to re-install I frequently got error below :

```
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.6-13+donate.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.0 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

Moreover I un-installed and re-install apache2 server also but not able to resolve it.
Please note initially I ran command `sudo apt-get update`. After that I have all these issues. Kindly suggest how it will resolved. Thanks